# Ошибка Insert запроса

Tags: sql

В бд(mysql) есть таблица, пытаюсь поместить строку так

```
INSERT INTO 'messages' ('id', 'author', 'poluchatel', 'date','text','read') VALUES ('1', 'legik', 'legik2', '11-10-23 20:11:14','uu','0')
```

Но phpmyadmin выдает ошибку:

> `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''messages' ('id', 'author', 'poluchatel', 'date','text','read') VALUES ('1', 'le' at line 1`

Таблица выглядит так

[image: таблица]

Answer (score 5):

Таблицы и поля обрамляются в косые кавычки (там где "ё" и тильда)

```
INSERT INTO `messages` (`id`, `author`, `poluchatel`, `date`,`text`,`read`) VALUES ('1', 'legik', 'legik2', '11-10-23 20:11:14','uu','0')
```

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: выберите ответ как правильный, если помогло.